# Is it possible to use Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol from inside the webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Is it possible from Inside the Chrome Browser to  connect to the [Remote Debugging Protoco](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/protocol/1.1/index)l? - without installing and creating extension for that purpose.

The purpose would be to test a JavaScript code created inside the HTML page using ACE editor or similar, to allow user to run code snippet within the page and then return the result to the calling page. For example, the code might be running inside an IFRAME.

At least http://brackets.io/ is said to *"Brackets is a web-based IDE that uses the Chrome debugging protocol to enable debugging and live HTML/CSS development.*" - which lets me wonder, is there client JS API for browser to connect with WebSockets to the interface or do you have to write that interface by yourself?

So, there seems to be several options for client, but what about the browser itself?

**EDIT**: assuming here that the browser was started with --remote-debugging-port=...  set to a meaningful value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. As far as I can tell, the remote debugging interface is only available if it has explicitly been enabled at startup using the `--remote-debugging-port=` command-line flag. There doesn't appear to be any way to activate it at runtime; even if it were, you wouldn't be able to access it from a web page.

Keep in mind that Brackets is a standalone application based on Chrome; it doesn't run as a web site. As such, it can do some things that aren't possible in a browser.

Now, that all being said, there may be a way to make some error reporting and debugging features available if you're careful. In particular, if you can inject code into your iframe, you could attach an event handler to [the global `onerror` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) to catch exceptions. You may need to use some special tricks to pass events from the frame to the parent page — [`Window.postMessage` may be helpful here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) — but that should at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming the the browser was started with --remote-debugging-port= ... enabled, but I was wondering if there was a client API to connect to it using websocket or if there is some other protocol using console... object

Comment: No, there isn't. The debugging interface is bound to `localhost`, so it's a different origin from any web site you're visiting, and thus not accessible.

Comment: Oh yes, that would be a horrible security hole indeed.